# G-Mail ignora CSS

Tags: css, email, envio-de-email, gmail

Galera, boa tarde!

O g-mail meio que ignora CSS nos e-mails que faço, ele nem aparece nos e-mails, e as vezes quando aparece, ele muda a class do que preciso pra uma class aleatória deles la. Como posso contornar isso?

Obrigado!

Comment: Nem todos o CSS é aceito por gerenciadores de email. Você não pode montar um email da mesma forma que faria um site.

Comment: Eu sei, mas necessito mesmo disso. Vou tentar usar CSS linkado. Inline ele aceita, mas não posso usar inline nesse momento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os problemas que você está tendo, pode ter referência com o como você está inserindo o CSS dentro do seu e-mail marketing.

- Em alguns clientes de e-mail, eles não abrem CSS dentro da `<head>`, sendo assim a melhor opção inserí-los dentro do `<body>` usando a tag `<style></style>`
- Em outros clientes nem inserindo por `class` ou `id` vai adiantar, o melhor é inserir através do atributo `style=""`

Mas, apesar de tudo, o que vale para um cliente não é garantido que vai funcionar no outro, ou seja, no Gmail pode funcionar mas no Outlook não. Por isso eu recomendo dar uma lida nesses guias sobre e-mail marketing, você terá uma noção maior do que pode e não pode fazer em e-mails.

[Mailchimp - Email Client CSS Support](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/)

[Campaign Monitor - The Ultimate Guide to CSS](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)